# Create or Update Rails 4 - updates but also creates (Refactoring)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In my Rails API I have the following code in my Child model:

```
before_create :delete_error_from_values, :check_errors, :update_child_if_exists

def delete_error_from_values
    @new_error = self.values["error"]
    @values = self.values.tap { |hs| hs.delete("error") }
end

def update_child_if_exists
    conditions = {type: self.type, parent_id: self.parent_id}

    if existing_child = Child.find_by(conditions)
        new_values = existing_child.values.reverse_merge!(@values)
        hash = {:values => new_values}
        existing_child.update_attributes(hash)
    end
end

def check_errors
    if self.type == "error"
        conditions = {type: self.type, parent_id: self.parent_id}
        if existing_child = Child.find_by(conditions) 
            bd_errors = existing_child.error_summary
            bd_errors[@new_error] = bd_errors[@new_error].to_i + 1
            hash = {:error_summary => bd_errors}
            existing_child.update_attributes(hash)
        else
            self.error_summary = {@new_error => 1}
        end
    end
end
```

This works like expected, except for one small detail: The Child is updated if a record by type and parent_id already exists, but it is also created. How can I refactor this to stop creation?

I've tried to include `return false`, but if I do this, the update is not successful.

I wish to have something like `find_or_create_by`, but I'm not sure how to use it for this cases.

Comment: I have problems parsing the sentence after a colon. Could you reword please?

Comment: I don't understand what you meant. What didn't you understand and what can I reword to help you?

Comment: @skimisha, What attributes does your Child model hold & what exactly you are trying to achieve before you save the child record ?

Comment: @skimisha, Your code can be really simplified once we get to know what you are trying to achieve in the before_create callback methods ?

Comment: @Ajay see my comment in your answer please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can refactor your code in following approach:

```
def create 
  @parent = Parent.find(params[:parent_id]) 
  existing_child = Child.where(type: child_params[:type], parent_id:    
  child_params[:parent_id]).first 

  if existing_child.present? 
    existing_child.update_attributes(attribute: value_1) 
  else 
    @child = @parent.child.build(child_params) 
  end 
  #other saving related code goes here.
end
```

This is just a basic piece of example. 
Try creating separate instance methods to keep the Contrller DRY. :)

Comment: That's not exactly my point. The update part works as expected and the record is updated if it exists but in the end, the record is also created (since it is called in the before_create it is still created). So I get the previously existing `Child` with the same `type` and `parent_id` updated, but I also get a new child. I'm trying to quit the `create` action if the `update` is successful by using the `find_or_create_by` method. Was I clearer?

Comment: as you are calling the 3 callbacks before_create, so when you update a record those callbacks should never get fired. Those will get fired only when youa are creating a new record.

Comment: This happens when I'm calling the create action. The point is when someone is trying to create a new record, the API verifies if a record of the same `type` and `parent_id` exists and if it does only a few fields are updated and the record is not created. I can't talk in chats, not enough rep :(